# How to data-bind control's property within ControlTemplate, to the data-context of the window that contains the control with this template?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding, controltemplate

I have this template:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Frame" x:Key="FrameControlTemplate">
    <!-- stuff, stuff, stuff, ... -->
        <Button Content="{Binding ButtonBackText}">
    <!-- stuff, stuff, stuff, ... -->
</ControlTemplate>
```

applied to this `Frame`:

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <loc:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <!-- stuff, stuff, stuff, ... -->
        <Frame Template="{StaticResource FrameControlTemplate}" />
    <!-- stuff, stuff, stuff, ... -->
</Window>
```

I need the `Button` that's in the `ControlTemplate` to bind its `Content` to the `DataContext` of the window (the `MainWindowViewModel` object).

From some reason, it doesn't show the text. Why is that?

Comment: Normally I would say you could do that with `RelativeSource` binding but it should work in XAML you provided as it is unless there is something in _stuff_ that changes default `DataContext`, like `ItemsControl` for its items. So don't know if there is bigger problem here or not

Comment: It is unclear whether the button in the template is a child member of <stuff, stuff, stuff> or an independent sibling. You need to provide an actual example in a new project which could be used by *us* to replicate the problem and subsequently provide an answer.

Comment: Use Snoop to look at the binding.  Should be revealing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically relying on the DataContext inheritance, which seems to be a not-so-good solution since you are using a frame and cannot be sure what is outside of that frame. It could easly happen, that someone or even you changes the DataContext somewhere outside the frame.

I would set the DataContext of your Button directly to the window.

```
//Button constructor
public Controltemplate(){
   myButton.DataContext = Window.GetWindow(this);
}
```

This code will now **not** inherit any DataContext from any parents and **bind directly to your window**.

---

**Update upon downvote:**
I didn't though about not beeing able to refrence the button using the Name.
However, it is quite easy to do that in a Template.

```
private Button _partButton = null;

public ControlTemplate{
   Loaded += (sender, e) => OnLoaded();
}

private void OnLoaded(){
   _partButton  = (Button)Template.FindName("PART_MyButton"); //You "should" use PART_ as a prefix in a Template
  if(_partButton  != null)
     _partButton.DataContext = Window.GetWindow(this);
}
```

Just make sure you also set `PART_MyButton` as the name of your Button.

Also you are Binding to `ButtonBackText` of your Window - You may need to check the Output Window for *"Data Binding Error: ..."* in case that Property does not exist on your Window.

Comment: I see why someone downvoted you, the initial thought of your logic is correct, but the application is wrong for there is no 'name' used in a control template, hence no 'myButton' to be directly accessed in code behind.

Comment: @OmegaMan Ups, quick fixes do not always work as expected :D Updated my answer